# How to prove $E|X|^p \le E|X+Y|^p$ given certain conditions?

Tags: probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v. such that $E|X|^p < \infty$ and $E|Y|^p < \infty$ for $p\ge 1$. Assume $EY=0$. Prove $E|X|^p \le E|X+Y|^p$.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Start with expectations conditional on $X$.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Comment: Another hint: use Jensen's inequality

Comment: It doesn't seem to lead to the conclusion. $E|X+Y|^p \ge |E(X+Y)|^p=|EX|^P$

Comment: It's because you haven't considered conditional on $X$ expectations first.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. $E|X+Y|^p=E[E(|X+Y|^p|X)] \ge E[|E(X+Y|X)|^P]=E|X|^p$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hints of Sergei Golovan:

Consider conditional expectation $ E(|X+Y|^p|\ X)$ and apply Jensen's inequality to it: 
$$E(|X+Y|^p|\ X )\geq |E(X+Y|\ X)|^p.
$$
Moreover, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $EY=0$, we have $E(X+Y|\ X)=X+EY=X$. This gives 
$$E(|X+Y|^p|\ X )\geq |X|^p, a.s.
$$
Now we take expectations on both sides in the last inequality and obtain:
$$E|X+Y|^p=E(E(|X+Y|^p|\ X ))\geq E|X|^p,
$$ 
as desired.